# Result of Math.round() is ignored

Tags: java, android

Why is it not working?I want to "odleglosc" is 2.2 not 2.214354356

[image]

Comment: `Math.round` doesn't round in place but returns a value. Since you never save the result to a variable, it is thrown away.

Comment: you are not storing the value returned by Math.round(). Use codeXXX= Math.round(codeXXX)

Comment: Another way to state this is that Java is call-by-value, not call-by-reference.   For your code to work, `Math.round(x)` would have to be a call-by-reference call.

Comment: This not work, because `Math.round` is int type, and it's rounding values by half up to the fully int value (not float/double). Let use `NumberFormat` class instead.

Answer (score 2):

[`Math.round(argument)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Math.html#round(double)) **returns** a number that is rounded from the argument.

In your example you ignore the returned value.

You probably meant to write:

```
 odleglosc = Math.round(odleglosc);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = Math.round(x);
```

Otherwise if you just write `Math.round(x);` 
Java will make the calculation and have no variable to assign it to, and gets thrown away.

Answer (score 0):

`Math.round()` does not modify your variable because a `double` the value is passed to the function (compare all-by-value vs call-by-reference).

To round your value use

```
a = Math.round(a);
```

Comment: And see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value